# Placing footer under content doesn't seem to work

Tags: html, css, positioning, footer

I'm trying to get the footer on a webpage under my content, regardless of the length of the content. For some reason, it doesn't want to.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="navigatie">
        <ul>
            <a class="navigatielink" href="index.php?page=home"><li class="navigatieli navigatie1">Home</li></a>
            <a class="navigatielink" href="index.php?page=info"><li class="navigatieli navigatie2">Info</li></a>
            <a class="navigatielink" href="index.php?page=agenda"><li class="navigatieli navigatie3 ">Agenda</li></a>
            <a class="navigatielink" href="index.php?page=fotos"><li class="navigatieli navigatie4">Foto's</li></a>
            <a class="navigatielink" href="index.php?page=contact"><li class="navigatieli navigatie5">Contact</li></a>
            <a class="navigatielink" href="index.php?page=gastenboek"><li class="navigatieli navigatie6">Gastenboek</li></a>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <?php
        //include the page content
        include_once ("content/".$_PAGE.'.php');
    ?>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="footer">
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
.footer {
    background-image: url("images/css/footer.png");
    height: 500px;
}

.navigatie {
    font-family: Rockwell;
    height: 45px;
    width: 980px;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-size: 24px; 
    border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
    background: #fff;
}
```

I already tried to give the `.container` a height of 100% and played with positioning, but I don't seem to be able to get this footer under the content regardless of the length of it...
Any more suggestions?

**EDIT:**
It's about [this website](http://www.dejeuzel.be/new/index.php)

Comment: you are absolute-positioning your content boxes..
no way you will ever get a simple clear element to fix your layout!

Comment: if you want to achieve a flexible layout, **get rid of absolute positioning** and use floating elements instead

Comment: @Lucius, thanks it did the tric! But problem is, sometimes I really need those absolute positionings...

Comment: You know, in most cases absolute positioning is sign of a lazy designer (no personal offense intended). So when you find yourself resorting to it, it should ring you a bell and you should ask yourself "isn't there really another way to achieve this without abs-pos?"

Comment: Haha, this is the best comment I had in year :-) So, is there any other way?

Comment: First of all, you need to determine whether the element you have to position needs to remain part of the flow of the document: if its width and/or height dinamically adapt to its contents, and this affects other elements in the page, it means that you should avoid absolute positioning by all means.
This is because abs-pos removes any element to which it is assigned from the normal flow of the document, so there is no more interaction with other elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have not mentioned the style which has been used for  `class="navigatie"` I guess you have used `float` property there. If so then add `overflow:hidden` to `.container`. For e.g.,

```
.container {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%; /* For IE6 */
    overflow:hidden /* For all other browsers*/
}
```

If my assumption is not right, then please provide the full list of elements present inside `.contaier` and also the full stylesheet.

**EDIT:**
 Try this

```
 HTML:
   <div class="contentPart">
      <?php
        //include the page content
       include_once ("content/".$_PAGE.'.php');
      ?>
 </div>

CSS:
.contentPart {
     overflow:hidden;
     height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, by adding the `overflow` property, the footer just positioned itself over the content... I've added the css for `.navigatie`

Comment: Just checked your code, well I think it would be better if you place the floating elements inside a parent element. just check my answer I am adding some staff in few mins.

Comment: Can you please update these changes which I mentioned and upload in the link you provided then it would help us to sort out.

Comment: Ok, please check again, I've added your suggestions!

Comment: @Michiel I just checked again, well your elements inside the `<div class="left">` are all using `position:absolute`, please remove the `position:absolute` from `<div class="news"> and <div class="fotos">`
As absoulute positioned elements doesn't has any existance thats the reason why the elements are not stretching heightwise.

news

Comment: Well, great! This was the solution. Damn positioning!! But if I delete the `absolute`, the small green arrows on the left side of the square will jump their own way... any way to avoid this kind of behavior?

Comment: provide a link to your design where the green arrows needs to be placed, I wil provide you the solution.

Comment: It's easy. If you see the small arrow on the right side under `Kalender`? There should the little arrows be placed...

Comment: okay great.. just add `position:relative` to `.news and .fotos`

Comment: you rock man!! You more then deserve the reputation!! Thanks a million!

Comment: Can I bother you once more with a positioning issue? If you go to the `foto's` page, you'll the photos are loading one at a time, but the frame in which they are positioned doesn't grow along... Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Well `<div class="photoalbum">` uses `float` property, hence its parent needs to have `overflow:hidden`. So the parent element is `<div class="photos">` add this style in your stylesheet `.photos { overflow: hidden; }`

Comment: You are freaking awesome! I wish I could give you even more reputation! Thanks again!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12696/discussion-between-subhajit-and-michiel)

Answer (score 0):

try adding a float:left; to .footer class

```
.footer{
  float:left;
}
```

if you can get a jsFiddle up it'll help massively

Comment: I tried that already. I've got something better, I've added the link to the website!